# Hoping to fast speed of reverse sort list

Tags: list, performance, sorting, netlogo, patch

*When there are 3 thousand patches,the speed of netlogo is normal. But when I change the size of world(99*99), the speed is too slow about 5 minutes update 10 tick. I am eager to improve the speed of it. The following is the code.

```
to publish
  set contribution_list  ( reverse sort [cumulative-contribution] of patches)
  let m count patches
  if contribution > item (round( m * shibei-proportion) ) contribution_list
    [set pcolor blue + 3]
  if contribution > item (round( m * (shibei-proportion + bian-proportion)) ) contribution_list
    [set pcolor blue + 2]
  if contribution > item (round( m * (shibei-proportion + bian-proportion + dahongbao-proportion))) contribution_list
    [set pcolor blue + 1]
  set cumulative-contribution 0
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is NetLogo too slow for big simulations? How can I speed up a NetLogo model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490078/is-netlogo-too-slow-for-big-simulations-how-can-i-speed-up-a-netlogo-model)

Comment: Without seeing the entire model it's difficult to be sure, but it appears that you are doing `[cumulative-contribution] of patches` for every patch or every turtle at every tick. If so, you should reorganize the code so it only happens once per tick, total.